# Curve top of div using CSS

Tags: wordpress, css, border

I am trying to curve the top of a div (like in this design: https://dribbble.com/shots/1691707-Sleek-Multipurpose-Webs%20ite-Part-2/attachments/268709), specifically the white div beneath the hero image on this WP theme: https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Hestia.

I have tried to apply the following logic, which I believe will give me what I want, but goes horribly wrong at each attempt:

```css
.main-raised {
margin: -200px -500px 0px -500px !important;
border-radius: 1150px 1150px 0px 0px !important;
z-index: 1 !important;
}

.hestia-features, .features {
padding: 75px 0 55px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main main-raised">
            <section class="features hestia-features" id="features" data-sorder="hestia_features">
                    <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                                <h2 class="hestia-title">Core features</h2>
                                                                        <h5 class="description">Example text</h5>
                                        </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="hestia-features-content">
    <div class="row">               <div class="col-md-4 feature-box">
                <div class="info hestia-info">
                                            <a href="#">
                                    <div class="icon" style="color:#e91e63">
            <i class="fa fa-wechat"></i>
                                    </div>
                                                                                                <h4 class="info-title">Responsive</h4>
                                                                            </a>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 feature-box">
                <div class="info hestia-info">
                                            <a href="#">
                                    <div class="icon" style="color:#00bcd4">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                    </div>
                                                                                                <h4 class="info-title">Quality</h4>
                                                                            </a>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 feature-box">
                <div class="info hestia-info">
                                            <a href="#">
                                    <div class="icon" style="color:#4caf50">
            <i class="fa fa-support"></i>
                                    </div>
                                                                                                <h4 class="info-title">Support</h4>
                                                                            </a>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                        </div>
            </div>
            </div><!-- /.row --><div class="row"></div>     </div>
                                </div>
```

Can anyone please advise how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself to get this to work? Before posting a question, it is expected that you have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please edit your question to add any updates, so that others will see them also and they are not lost in the comments.

Comment: I have done this - thanks.

Comment: At the moment your divs are empty so they are not showing any effect. Should they have content, or a a minimum height set for example?

Comment: I have tried to provide some additional detail in my question - does this help?

Comment: The code you’re added is clearly not an MCVE.

Comment: The new code doesn't seem to  relate in any way to your initial code to create the curve?
Please update the code snippet with the relevant code to make it work so that we can see what you have tried and where the problem is. We cannot help if we cannot see working code and the actual problem.

Comment: I have done this and when running the snippet, the curve at the top of div is showing, but I need to now remove the curve at the bottom of the div?

Comment: I have progressed relatively far with this, but now have a horrid overflow issue with the border-radius property. Can anyone please help with removing this? Overflow: hidden doesn't effect anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the border-radius property.

You can modify each corner using a shorthand value like so.

border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

This will give the top-left and top-right corners a radius of 15px each and the bottom corners a radius of 0 each.

Further reading here, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: The example you posted was using border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; Just have a look at their css using your browsers Inspector.

Comment: I have progressed relatively far with this, but now have a horrid overflow issue with the border-radius property. Can anyone please help with removing this? Overflow: hidden doesn't effect anything. Thanks.